# why does passing a string as "this" cause this weirdness?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why javascript is doing something unexpected (to me).  Here's a bit of code that's purely for example.  In other words, I don't actually want to extend String (I'm actually binding to functions and stuff).  So this is plain javascript with no libraries.

```
var s = 'blah';

String.prototype.foo = function () {
  console.log('this === s:', this === s);
  console.log('this == s:', this == s);
  console.log('typeof this:', typeof this);
  console.log('typeof s:', typeof s);
  console.log('this:', this);
  console.log('s:', s);
};

s.foo()
```

And here's the output in Safari's script console:

```
this === s: false
this == s: true
typeof this: object
typeof s: string
this: [object Object]
s: blah
```

Similar output in IE, FF, Chrome, etc.

I'm trying to wrap my head around why this === s is not true.  Also why this is an "object" but s is a "string".

What's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *"Also why this is an "object" but s is a "string"."*

It'll be easier if we start with this one.

This is because when you call a method on a primitive value, it is converted to its object wrapper for you (since that's where the methods are). This means that the `this` value in the function will be the object wrapper, and not the primitive string.

It's as though you were doing this:

```
new String( s ).foo();
```

So this explains the `typeof` result and the `[object Object]` output.

---

> *"I'm trying to wrap my head around why this === s is not true."*

This is probably more understandable now. Because `this` is not a reference to the original string, but rather its object wrapper, you're not comparing identical items by any definition of `===`.

The reason `==` works is that it does type coercion. The Object wrapper is converted to a string primitive, and so you end up with an equal comparison.

---

You should note that if you're running your code in *strict mode*, and you call the method on a primitive, the value of `this` will be the primitive instead of its object wrapper.

Comment: So, much in the way that calling "typeof (new String('blah'))" will return "object", I guess.  Good to know yet another "thing that javascript does to help you but just winds up being confusing."

Answer (score 0):

When you compare something using === it compares it by value and by type. Since this is an object and s is a string, it fails. In most cases this refers to the parent object. Either a html object or the window. With no preparation of this, this == window object. this can also be the class object and can be compared that way as well. Since you are prototyping the String class it automatically becomes an object.

List of comparision operators: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp